# How to reliably flush rewrite rules on multisite?

Tags: multisite, rewrite-rules

Let's say you have a plugin which need to flush rewrite rules. You do it all properly with activation hook and adding flush late, so everything is smooth and compatible.

And then one fine day someone tries to run it on multisite.

Instead of a simple scenarios like:

1. WordPress site is created
2. Plugin is installed and activated

You now have nightmare scenarios like:

1. Plugin is installed and network activated
2. New WordPress site (or a hundred) in multisite is created

In theory it should just work, right? In practice it goes wrong in spectacular ways:

- `$wp_rewrite` state can be from the wrong site
- `switch_to_blog()` doesn't track rewrite state either
- the “later” part might happen in different blog entirely
- all those *other* plugins, you are supposed to play nice with, might not be consistently enabled on different sites

For example you can see this issue how trying to do it right [blows away permalinks on main site every time new site is created](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/2239).

So how would plugin go about **reliably** flushing rewrite rules **in multisite**:

1. When new site is created, for the site?
2. When existing site is activated from inactive, for the site?
3. When plugin is network activated, for every site?
4. When plugin is network deactivated, for every site?
5. Possibly in other scenarios, involving rewrite global context getting changed?

Answer (score 13):

**Note: this is an incomplete answer which will be expanded upon incrementally**

---

The only reliable way to flush rewrite rules in multisite, without potentially destroying the permalink structure of the primary and or any other blog context (depending upon how and what you a switching to and from) is to flush rewrite rules in a given context like so:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->init(); //important...
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

The above ensures that correct permalink structure for the given context is retrieved and set prior to constructing the rewrite rules and commiting the changes to the database.

This does not apply to single site where context does not matter, because there is only one context.

`flush_rewrite_rules()` in my opinion is flawed in the premise that it assumes the correct context, but does not take into account our use of `switch_to_blog` for which completely changes the context and leaves us in dangerous territory if we try to flush rules, potentially.

This is what the internals of `flush_rewrite_rules()` looks like:

```
function flush_rewrite_rules( $hard = true ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( $hard );
}
```

I cannot think of a reason why it shouldn't look like this:

```
function flush_rewrite_rules( $hard = true ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->init(); //hello....
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( $hard );
}
```

...especially when you consider that the constructor of `WP_Rewrite` does what? It does this...

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->init();
}
```

Touching on your first point of concern to further this line of though,

> So how would plugin go about reliably flushing rewrite rules in **multisite**:
>
> - When new site is created, for the site?

Let's look at what WordPress core will notably call during this process:

- first `wpmu_create_blog()`
- which then calls `install_blog()` which in turn calls `populate_options()`
- then `populate_options()` sets default permalink structure in options table
- after `install_blog()` has ran, `wp_install_defaults()` then gets called
- then `wp_install_defaults()` flushes the rewrite rules for the newly created site before finally switching back to the current blog via `restore_current_blog()`.

Importantly to note is that [`wp_install_defaults()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L250) flushes rules exactly as I've suggested above above:

```
$wp_rewrite->init();
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

...because that's the only way to be sure the correct `permalink_structure` and rules are built for the current context.

Also in the problem evidenced within the [Github issue](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/2239#issue-67152032), the reason why the user experienced the following behavior:

> When a new site is created it breaks the post level permalinks only on the top level site - in most permalink configurations but not all:
>
> These 2 formats work correctly.
>
> Default - Works as expected
>
> Day & Name - Works as expected

...is because if the primary blog has a Day & Name permalink structure `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`, when a new site is created, it too has a Day & Name permalink structure `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` by default which is why no notable problem presents itself when the Yoast SEO plugin flushes rewrite rules on the `shutdown` hook.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Annoying thing with installing a new site is that you cannot hook during the process, only after it has already been completed. Because of that the rules will be flushed twice.

Comment: Bounty time run out, so points for falling on the sword here. :) Still a lot to figure out though. :(

Comment: Is it not possible to manually set the context of `$wp_rewrite` so that you could loop through and reset each network site?  

I have a large network site that is suffering from some permalink issues on custom plugins.  Making a plugin that adds a cron seems overkill as it would always be resetting them. Looping them with a custom URL would be ideal but I don't know how to do it for all sites.